# How to handle keyboard events in LimeJS javascript for html5

Tags: javascript, html, limejs

I am a beginner in limeJS i want to know how to handle keyboard events in a game using limejs for html5.If one have a source link for it please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Lime is built on Closure, you can just use its native event library.

For example:

```
goog.events.listen(rootLimeNodeObject, goog.events.EventType.KEYUP, function (ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode === 37) { // left arrow
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the guides look pretty obscure, but i would recomend that you use a seperate library like Keyboard js. It's a really good library for keyboard events and it would be the easiest option.

http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/

a demo would be:

```
KeyboardJS.bind.key('a', onDownCallback(), onUpCallback() );
```

and this for multiple keys:

```
KeyboardJS.bind.key('a + b ', onDownCallback(), onUpCallback() );
```